# BufferedReader not visible to other functions

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

I have a train.csv file which contains StackOverflow questions in the form of "id","title","body" and "tag". I wanted to extract questions from the beginning and store them in a proper format in another text file. So I was writing this program. In the program I have written a `StringBetweenQuotes()` function. I use a `BufferedReader` named `training_data` for my train.csv file. My question is simple, the way I have declared a protected `training_data` for the entire class, I thought once it would be visible to `StringBetweenQuotes` when it uses it. But I am getting a Java IO Exception. How to deal with it ?

```
import java.io.*;

public class ExtractData {
    protected static BufferedReader training_data;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        training_data = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/trafalgar_law/Desktop/ML-CourseProject/Train/Train.csv"));
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/trafalgar_law/Desktop/ML-CourseProject/Train/FormattedOutput.txt" ));

        int count = 0;
        int r, Id;
        char ch;
        String line = training_data.readLine();
        StringBuffer id = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuffer title = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuffer body = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuffer tags = new StringBuffer("");

        while(true) {
            id = StringBetweenQuotes();
            output.write("Id:\n" + id);
            r = training_data.read();

            title = StringBetweenQuotes();
            output.write("Title:\n" + title);
            r = training_data.read();

            body = StringBetweenQuotes();
            output.write("Body:\n" + body);
            r = training_data.read();

            tags = StringBetweenQuotes();
            output.write("Tags:\n" + tags);
            r = training_data.read();

            Id = Integer.parseInt(id.toString());
            if (Id > 3) break;
            //++count;
        }
        training_data.close();
        output.close();
    }

    public static StringBuffer StringBetweenQuotes() {
        StringBuffer buffer= new StringBuffer("");

        /*
        Method to extract text between quotes
        training_data will be used here
        */
        return buffer;
    }


}
```

Comment: The IOException is not happening because of the protected field... show the stacktrace so we can help. I see you are on unix system and accessing a file from specific user home path, make sure you have the permission to access the file.

Comment: `IOException` has nothing to do with field scope or visibility. Please show us the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please

- don't use StringBuffer, these were replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago.
- don't initialise a StringBuilder with an empty String. This only hurts performance.
- don't create dummy values for StringBuilders which you discard.
- don't pass variables via static fields. I suggest you pass it as an argument.

Also don't ignore IOExceptions, you should catch them instead or in this case, I suggest you rethrow it.

This is how I would write it, using an existing StringBuilder

```
public static void stringBetweenQuotes(BufferedReader br, StringBuilder sb) 
       throws IOException {
    sb.setLength(0);
```